# Does ehCache have any option of auto refreshing?

Tags: spring, ehcache

Does ehCache have any feature of auto refreshing? If yes, please let me know how to do that. If not, please let me know few possible and efficient ways in which ehCache refresh can be done.

Comment: What do you mean by auto-refresh?

Comment: The scenario is like this.
I have an ehCache implemented. The ehcache has to be refreshed every day at 12:12AM. So can ehcache trigger the refresh itself at 12:12 AM everday automatically or we need to use timers  to trigger the same.

Comment: or is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: I take it that the data that is inserted into EhCache is produced by some business method? Correct?

Comment: Correct. The data is inserted into ehcache through business method. At 12:12 AM everyday the ehcache has to be evicted and reloaded with fresh values

Comment: Check out my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way for EhCache to know how the data that was inserted into to it, was produced. That part is totally application specific. There fore EhCache cannot refresh itself automatically- it can't pull the data, the data has to be pushed into it.

In order to do that you need to add another component to your application that will run at a scheduled time and while insert the appropriate data into EhCache.

Spring has awesome support for scheduled tasks. Check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) part of the documentation

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Geoand. 1 more doubt.Will not "SelfPopulatingCache" help us in achieving this?

Comment: That's a good point, however with `SelfPopulatingCache` you still need to have a scheduler that will call refresh. You have coupled the cache with it's read strategy, but you still need to tell it when to refresh. Check out http://java.dzone.com/news/using-selfpopulatingcache. I also don't know if you can use Spring @Cacheable support with `SelfPopulatingCache`

Answer (score 3):

ehCache has builtin eviction algorithms that you can use by setting timeToIdleSeconds and timetoLiveSeconds this will tell ehcache when to eject that data from the cache and force a reload of the data from your persistence data source. Read the following ehCache document on more detailed instruction on configuring TTL http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration/data-life

Comment: Thanks Bell. That was of great help to me.